# Overlay app store images with bootstrap 3 responsive site

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not sure if 'overlay' is the correct term here. Basically I have 2 columns with images in them with img-responsive set on them to take up the entire column so when viewed on smaller devices they stack. In the right side column I want to overlay apple and google store icons at a certain position. However when I'm resizing my window to test how it'll look on different screen sizes these app store images do not stay relative in position or size. I'm not the best at CSS so I'm sure I'm missing something but ideally you'd want these app store images to position the exact same and resize themselves so everything stays relative and looks the same.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- SAID BY SIDE IMAGES -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12  col-sm-6" style="background-color: green; padding: 0;">
            <img class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto;" src="~/Content/Images/Middle_1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="background-color: blue; padding: 0; position: relative;">
            <img class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto;" src="~/Content/Images/Middle_2.jpg" alt="">

        <!-- THIS IMAGE NEEDS TO LOOK THE SAME IN POSITION AND RESIZE ITSELF BASED ON THE SCREEN WIDTH SO IT LOOKS THE SAME ON ANY WIDTH -->
            <img style="position: absolute; width: 120px; height: 40px; top: 300px; left: 10px;" src="~/Content/Images/Apple_App_Store_badge.jpg" />
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Are you looking for overlay? when you hover on the image, you wanna display icon?

Comment: @SaiManoj I just wanted images to be on top if each other. I did get this figured out though. I made the parent div relative in position, then the child elements absolute and used percentages in size and top/left so that it flexes correctly with the column and that all works.